# Get sum of objects before with linq

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I have list like below.

List

- 3 John
- 1 Scully
- 4 Edward
- 9 Kim

Trying to convert this with linq to;

List

- 3 John
- 4 Scully
- 8 Edward
- 17 Kim

How can i do that without for loop. I want to achieve this with linq.

Comment: Could you explain what this numbers means?

Comment: what does your current Linq look like?

Comment: OMG worst explanation ever, what does that numbers mean!?

Comment: Does the list contain strings? Tuples? Something else? Do you want to modify an existing list or create a new one?

Comment: I think I get it is the sum of values, so John = 3 + 1, Scully = 4 + 1 + 3, Edward = 9 + 4 + 1 + 3

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Yes its sum of values before the current object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a method to do that in LINQ already; you're going to have to write your own.  Try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> AggregatingSelect<TItem, TAggregate, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TItem> items,
        Func<TItem, TAggregate, TAggregate> aggregator,
        TAggregate initial,
        Func<TItem, TAggregate, TResult> projection)
    {
        TAggregate aggregate = initial;
        foreach (TItem item in items)
        {
            aggregate = aggregator(item, aggregate);
            yield return projection(item, aggregate);
        }
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new[] { 3, 1, 4, 9 };
        var result = numbers.AggregatingSelect(
            (int item, int agg) => item + agg, 
            0, 
            (int item, int agg) => agg);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with a classic for loop. Way more simple, understandable, maintainable and efficient.

LINQ is basically not designed to update items depending on previous ordered values of a given list.

Comment: Though everything seems to be cooler with LINQ for some unknown reason :)

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar yes, I don't get the general "I want to do this with LINQ, no loops please". The funny thing is, LINQ always executes loops internally...